# Same python script works in one computer but not in another

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following script in Python 3.8 (32 bit):

```
import sys
import time

from Crypto.Cipher import AES

which_file = str(sys.argv[1])
if which_file == "license_service":
    nameoffiles = "C:\\file1.txt"
else:
    nameoffiles = "C:\\file2.txt"

file_names = open(nameoffiles, "r")
filenames = file_names.read()
filenames1 = filenames.split(',')
key_location = "path_to_key"
key_to_encrypt = open(key_location, "rb")
key = key_to_encrypt.read()
key_to_encrypt.close()

for x in filenames1:
    file_in = open(x, "rb")
    nonce, tag, ciphertext = [file_in.read(x) for x in (16, 16, -1)]
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_EAX, nonce)
    data = cipher.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, tag)
    file_in.close()
    file_out = open(x, "wb")
    file_out.write(data)
```

This script reads a file containing paths to files that need to be decrypted, then decrypted the files.

The problem is that in one computer (physical machine) it works perfect, never fails, and in another computer (a virtual machine) outputs the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\github\encrypt2\decrypt.py", line 26, in 
    file_out = open(x, "wb")
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found

Since the code works OK in one computer, I don't know what can I do to solve this, except to try to find difference between computers configurations.

Couldn't find any difference.

Comment: What are the operating systems/python versions?

Comment: python 38 32 bit, the physical is windows 10 2017 enterprise, the VM is windows 10 pro 2019

Comment: print x before file_out=open(..) and see why it is something an int on not a string

Answer (score 1):

Solved, the vm has also installed python 2.7, after uninstalling and set var path to 3.8 everything worked well